# React error: call child method in parent component

Tags: reactjs

```
class AUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.list = React.createRef();
  }
  handleChangeDataList = () => {
    this.list.current.reloadAUserTable();
  }
  render(){
   return(
     <AUserList
       ref={(ref) => { this.list = ref; }}
     />
     <Button onClick={() => this.handleChangeDataList()}>atest</Button>
   )
  }
}

class AUserList extends React.Component {
  reloadAUserTable = () => {
    console.log('good');
  }
}
```

But after click the button, I met this error

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: React version:    "react": "^16.8.6",

Comment: AUserList: What is the purpose of this class?

Comment: I have to make one react bootstrap table will be change some data via the parent's event.

Comment: I need one method to use this component.
this.dataSet.setData(this.props.data);
<BootstrapTable data={AUserData_arr} version="4" striped hover pagination search tabIndexCell />
......
github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is `unidirectional` it means you cannot access a method from the child component into your parent component ( it's not a good practice ) but what you can do is to place `reloadAUserTable()`inside the parent component and pass the reference has a prop.

This is also called **Level-up**

```
class AUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.list = React.createRef();
  }
  handleChangeDataList = () => {
    this.list.current.reloadAUserTable();
  }
  reloadAUserTable = () => {
    console.log('good');
  }
  render(){
   return(
     <AUserList
       ref={(ref) => { this.list = ref; }}
     />
     <Button onClick={() => this.handleChangeDataList()}>atest</Button>
   )
  }
}
```

Now pass it has a `prop` then, this way your parent component will have easy access to the method and also child component can access it through the **props** been passed.

Comment: sorry, but I have to change child component state on this event.

Comment: <BootstrapTable data={AUserData_arr} version="4" striped hover pagination search tabIndexCell />

Comment: I need one method to use this component.

Comment: this.dataSet.setData(this.props.data);

Comment: https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/30.
please check this link.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/9102103xjo
Please someone explain why it doesn't work for me